# How to filter rows with condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, average, amazon-athena, sql-null

I am trying to retrieve data from Athena with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cop.shop_id,
         cop.product_id,
         avg(cop.position) AS avg_position,
         cp.kes
FROM data_1 AS cop
JOIN data_2 AS cp
    ON cop.product_id = cp.product_id
WHERE cop.site_id = 1
        AND cop.product_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  cop.shop_id, cop.product_id, cp.kes
```

However, there are four columns in the data: product_id, shop_id, avg_position, kes.

Some rows come with both NA and non-NA in the `kes` column. I simply want to manipulate the data with the following condition:

- If `product_id` , `shop_id` , and `avg_position`  are the same, and if there are NA and Non-NA in the `kes`  column, just leave the Non-NA row and remove the rows which include NA in the `kes` .
- However, if there is no non-NA in the `kes` , don't remove it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want aggregation on `kes`:

```
SELECT 
    cop.shop_id,
    cop.product_id,
    AVG(cop.position) AS avg_position,
    MAX(cp.kes) kes
FROM data_1 AS cop
JOIN data_2 AS cp
    ON cop.product_id = cp.product_id
WHERE cop.site_id = 1 AND cop.product_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cop.shop_id, cop.product_id
```

Aggregate functions ignore `null` values; so `MAX(cp.kes)` gives you the highest non-`null` value of `cp.kes`. On the other hand, if all values of `cp.kes` are `null` within the group, `max()` gives `null`.

Side note: `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` do not make sense together (although that's still valid SQL); `GROUP BY` guarantees no duplicate values in the `SELECT` list already.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! It helped me a lot.